# Find suggested contact by email domain name

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts, address-book

I've been searching and searching for this and cannot find a solution. It baffles me totally.  In the suggested contacts list for Outlook 2010, how do I get it to search by "domain name"?  For example, say I have the following contacts in my Suggested Contacts:

- Jake Doe (jaked@thedomain.com)
- John Doe (johnd@thedomain.com)

In Outlook 2010, if I begin to type the beginning of the name, say "Jake" or "John", I will get a suggested popup for their respective name/email address.  However, if I type "thedomain.com", I get no matches.  Further, if I click into the Address Book and try searching for "thedomain.com", I get no matches, using More Columns, Advanced Find, or whatever.

Outlook clearly knows the domain -- heck it even shows as a separate column called "Domain" in the NK2 file with NK2Edit -- why on earth will it not pop up the suggested email when I type in a domain name?  What am I missing in my configuration to get this seemingly obvious thing working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: the names that pop up when you start typing into the `To:` field are not linked to your contacts, it's its own list (of addresses you previously entered into the To field).

Anyhow, to the question at hand:

AFAIK There's no native way to search Outlook contacts by domain name.

To can gain that ability you'll probably have to resort to a 3rd party plug-in.

One example would be [AbleBits' Smart Contacts](https://www.ablebits.com/outlook-contacts/):

> Smart Contacts is an assistant for quick and convenient work with
>   email addresses in Microsoft Outlook 2013, 2010, and 2007. Right after
>   installation this little address keeper displays your recent and
>   frequent contacts on a pane and lets you email them in a click.
>
> - See your favorite, frequent, and recent contact groups
> - **Instantly find Outlook address by entering any part of it, like the company or domain name**
> - Find Outlook contacts and double-click a listed address to create an e-mail
> - Add To, CC, or BCC recipients in a click
> - Click once to add contacts to Outlook address book after you reply to a message

*Note:* I have no affiliation with this software or company, nor have I ever actually tried it...

Comment: Hmm.. it looks like this is about the best solution.  I don't really want to spend $30 just to get emails by domain name when there are other simple ways to get that information :(  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. Just open the Suggested Contacts folder, click in the Search box and select **Search Tools -> Advanced Find...** on the ribbon. Now you can type "thedomain.com" (including quotes) to the **Search for the words:** box, select **"e-mail fields only"** in the **In:** box and click the **Find Now** button.

Comment: That is for searching mail, not addresses. In fact, you can just type domains in the standard mail search and it will work fine. I think this question is about how to find addresses when composing mail.